# When interchanging limit and supremum over a finite set is allowed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Suppose I have an element $x\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ in $\ell^\infty$. Fix $i\in\mathbb N$ and $x_m(i)$ converges to some $x(i)\in\mathbb R$ Let $N\in\mathbb N$. When does $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{1\le i\le N}|x
(i)-x_m(i)|=\sup_{1\le i\le N}\lim_{m\to\infty}|x
(i)-x_m(i)|$$ hold?

Comment: Does $(x_m(i))$ converge for all $1\le i \le N$? Then both sides are equal zero.

Comment: Since you just take a supremum over a _finite_ number of indexes, this is allowed true with the condition you mentionned.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo what condition do you mean? Does it follow from $x\in\ell^\infty$ or from the fact that $x_m(i)$ converges to $x(i)$ (for $i$ fixed)?

Comment: I meant the condition of convergence.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo : how does that follow from convergence?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that $i$ was fixed. First, we have to be sure that all the terms in the equality exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your right-hand side is equal to zero. For the left hand side,
$$
0\leq\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{1\leq i\leq N}|x(i)-x_m(i)|
=\lim_{m\to\infty}\max_{1\leq i\leq N}|x(i)-x_m(i)|
\leq\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N|x(i)-x_m(i)|\\
=\sum_{i=1}^N\lim_{m\to\infty}|x(i)-x_m(i)|
=\sum_{i=1}^N0=0.
$$
So the left-hand side is also zero.